# UICollectionView using UICollectionViewFlowLayout is centering and misaligning cells

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm using a standard `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` but it seems to do some overwork as it is centering the cells of section with one item and if the section contains 2 or 3 items, they are not distributed to fit width

How to get always the same distribution (to left) and margins (as with more than 3 items)

[image]

Comment: can you share the code for your collection view delegate and datasource functions?

Comment: i am returning the same size for the cells, so nothing fancy

Comment: Well you would need something fancy, namely a flow layout subclass.

Comment: Also are you using self sizing cells? That’s buggy. You need to show your code.

Comment: found the problem, see answer

Answer (score -2):

I found out what the problem was... the title text with (with the gray line separator) is also a cell that correspond to fullwidth, if this cell is together with the same sized cells i get the result described above

**So the solution was to keep only the same sized image cells in one section, without the fullwidth title cell** (Note: it is also better to rework the title cell into a section header in this case)

[image]